# Sequel Pro Connection to mysql server

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I want to connect to my DO droplet via sequelpro. Therefore I took the following steps:

**mysql my.conf**

```
[mysqld]

...

bind-address = DROPLET IP
```

**mysql**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' INDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH ALL PRIVILEGES;
```

**SEQUELPRO**
[image]

The error message I get is then:

[image]

Can you help me on this please? I seem to miss out on something

Answer (score 0):

Edit your my.conf
Comment out this line

```
[mysqld]
...
# bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
```

mysql:

```
grand all on  *.*  to root@'%'  identifies  by 'yourPassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Sequel Pro:

[image]

Hope helpful.